# String interpolation for complex object in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a complex object which is coming from my component :

```html
{
    "result": true,
    "metrics": {
        "callCounters": "",
        "campaignDetails": {
            "CampaignCount": 123,
            "DepartmentCount": 25
        },
        "callTypeCounts": {
            "IncomingCallCountBase": 59644,
            "IncomingCallCount": 0,
            "OutgoingCallCountBase": 2627223,
            "OutgoingCallCount": 0,
            "ManualCallCount": 6,
            "IvrCallCount": 0,
            "IvrCallCountBase": 1270098
        },
        "campaignCallCounts": []
    }
}
```

& my component.ts code looks like this.

```js
import { CampaignService } from './../../../services/campaign.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'campaign-header',
  templateUrl: './campaign-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./campaign-header.component.css']
})
export class CampaignHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  metricsInfo : any[];

  constructor(private campaignService:CampaignService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.campaignService.MetricsInfo()
    .subscribe(response =>{
      debugger;
      console.log(response.json())
      this.metricsInfo = response.json();
     
    })

  }
 
}
```

Also my service looks like this :

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Http
} from '@angular/http';
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CampaignService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  MetricsInfo() {

    return this.http.get('http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/portal/api/landingPageMetrics');
  }

}
```

I want to print `"IncomingCallCountBase"` to my `component.html` page in Angular 6 application.

I tried something like this, `{{ metricsInfo?.metrics.callTypeCounts.IncomingCallCountBase }}` but, it's not working. Also how can I add two fields "**IncomingCallCountBase**" & "**OutgoingCallCountBase**" Any help is much appreciated!

**NOTE:** "**metricsInfo**" is my component subscribed object.

**P.S : This log is after trying the solution.**

[[image: This is my console error log]

Comment: its working here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwoiwx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Strange! I wonder where I did a mistake, agh! anyways! Thank you. Further more can I add the numbers of"IncomingCallCountBase" and "OutgoingCallCountBase" in my component.ts page and put it in another variable and pass to the component view? Much thanks in advance. :)

Comment: check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwoiwx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Define "doesn't work", precisely. Use basic debugging techniques, like simply looking at what `metricsInfo` is by adding `{{ metricsInfo | json }}` to your template. You defined it as `any[]`, which means you intend it to be an array. But your JSON is not an array, and you're not using it as an array. So, what is it? And why do you use `any`in the first place, instead of defining a proper interface for it? And why do you still use the old, deprecated since version 4.3, Http service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see You have implemented the service in Angular 5 way (i.e no map explicitly for service response).

But the `http` object you have created using  `Http` . It should be created using `HttpClient` because `Http` is now deprecated.

If you want to use `Http` then modify your code in following way (not recommended) :

```js
// in component.service.ts file

MetricsInfo() {

    return this.http.get('http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/portal/api/landingPageMetrics')
    .map((response:Response) => {
            console.log("From  service == ", response.json());
            return response.json();
        }); 
  }
  
  //in component.ts file 
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadInitialData();
  }
  
  // loads inial data
  
  
  loadInitialData(){
   this.campaignService.MetricsInfo()
    .subscribe(response =>{
      this.metricsInfo = response;
      this.getTotal();
    })
  }
```

```html
<!-- In component.html  -->
<div class="container">
  {{ metricsInfo?.metrics.callTypeCounts.IncomingCallCountBase }}
  </div>
```

If you want to Use the `Httpclient` then modify your code in following way :

```js
// in component.service.ts file
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http'; // import Httpclient

// create Httpclient object
// you might need to adjust headers and requestObject **if you are using 


constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient,
  ) {}



MetricsInfo() {
    return this._http.get('http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/portal/api/landingPageMetrics');
  }
  
  //in component.ts file 
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadInitialData();
  }
  
  // loads inial data 
  
  loadInitialData(){
   this.campaignService.MetricsInfo()
    .subscribe(response =>{
      this.metricsInfo = response;
      this.getTotal();
    })
  }
```

Coming back to Addition , You can use The suggestion by @Prudhvi:

```js
getTotal(){
  return this.metricsInfo.metrics.callTypeCounts.IncomingCallCount + this.metricsInfo.metrics.callTypeCounts.OutgoingCallCountBase;
}
```

Comment: Sir, the method "getTotal()" should be fired on **ngOnInit()**  when I called it via the OnInit it throws an error saying **metrics is not defined**

Comment: Call  getTotal()  inside the subscribe of MetricsInfo() service . I updated the answer. check

Comment: It did worked. but my console is full of errors.I've attached the console error log after trying your solution.

Comment: i am not able to find ? where did you attach ?

Comment: I did something like this in my view. {{ getTotal() }}

Comment: That's because getTotal() will be called  when initializing the page. Do something like : <div *ngIf="metricsInfo">{{ getTotal() }} </div>

Comment: Okay. Thanks, you save a ton of my time. :)  @programoholic